# System.out.println not recognized in Pramp?

Tags: java

Can anyone point out why I'm getting an error for System.out.println? I'm trying to test the output. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Solution {

  static int[] getIndicesOfItemWeights(int[] arr, int limit) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for(int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++){
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == limit){
          return new int[] {i, j};
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getIndiciesOfItemWeights([1,3,2],4));
  }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:
/home/pramper/src/main/java/Solution.java:19: error: illegal start of expressionSystem.out.println(getIndiciesOfItemWeights([1,3,2],4));^

Comment: Typo. The function you declared doesn't have the same name as the function you are calling. (`Indicies` != `Indices`)

Comment: Will not fix the problem but the class of the main method must be public, it must be accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `[1,3,2]` isn't valid. You are supposed to use `new int[]{1,2,3}`. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Because of a few different bugs, your syntax for creating an inline array is off. Your method must have a return statement if the loop condition isn't met. And you want to call `Arrays.toString` to print the contents of your array. Finally, your method is `getIndicesOfItemWeights` (not `getIndiciesOfItemWeights`). Like,

```
static int[] getIndicesOfItemWeights(int[] arr, int limit) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == limit) {
                return new int[] { i, j };
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[0];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getIndicesOfItemWeights(
            new int[] { 1, 3, 2 }, 4)));
}
```

Outputs

```
[0, 1]
```